# Should I use tcmalloc/jemalloc replace memory pool?

Tags: performance, pool, tcmalloc

In my project, I use memory pool (boost::pool), but it eat too much memory(measured 22G), so I want to use tcmalloc/jemalloc replace memory pool, I consider the sides below:

```
1.performance
2.memory use
```

I think if I use tcmalloc/jemalloc replace pool, then the memory used will be smaller, but the performance issue will raise. How could I solve it? Thanks!